# ÅØÆ - Trouble with the text encoding from HTML -> Java -> MySQL -> Java -> HTML

Tags: java, mysql, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently working on my homepage which is entirely supported by a number of java classes and a MYSQL database.

I have a form in HTML where I allow viewers to input a comment. This text is then parsed by a CGI script to the java class where i read the text with:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String[] data = {in.readLine()};
```

The comment is then parsed on to the database with the following:

```
Connection conn;
        forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pagebuilder";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pagebuilder?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
        //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pagebuilder?characterEncoding=utf-8";       
        String userName = "username";
        String password = "password";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        return conn;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        conn.close();
    }

    public static void comment(String image, String name, String comment, String email){

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = Database.getConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            java.sql.Timestamp  sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO comment VALUES(0,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt1.setTimestamp(1,sqlDate);
            pstmt1.setString(2, image);
            pstmt1.setString(3, name);
            pstmt1.setString(4, comment);
            pstmt1.setString(5, email);

            pstmt1.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        }
```

If I input special Danish characters like `æøp` or even commas the output is as follows:

Input: `,æøå`

Output: `%2C%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5`

How do I keep input and output the same?

I have made several attempts of setting the HTML, Java connection and the database to UTF-8 but with no luck.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CGI program is receiving the text encoded like that.

%2C is the urlencoded version of a comma (0x2c in hex, 32+12 = 44 in decimal -- 44 is ascii comma http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

%C3%A6 is the urlencoded version of the UTF-8 encoded version of æ

%C3%B8 is the urlencoded version of the UTF-8 encoded version of ø

%C3%A5 is the urlencoded version of the UTF-8 encoded version of å

What you need to do is:
(a) convert your raw urlencoded stream to a urldecoded stream; and then
(b) interpret your urldecoded stream as UTF-8

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. The characters are now inserted into the database correctly. Now i just need to get them out correctly and have them displayed. Currently i get ???. Many thanks for your help

Comment: When are you getting the ??? - from the webbrowser? Does it display correctly from the mysql command line client?

Comment: I fixed it by adding encoding to my output writer in Java. This fixed the problem and everything is now displaying as it should. Once again, many thanks for your help.